# Create ReviewApp(Node.js) on a Heroku

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, heroku, npm, npm-install

When generating ReviewApp of ionic-app(using "express"), `npm install` is automatic executed on heroku. Since 'ionic-deploy' package is described in package.json, `npm install` will fail.

Detail:

`npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for ios-deploy@1.9.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})`

---

I thought and solved the following solution...

(Its not to delete 'ios-deploy' package from package.json)

1. Move package from dependencies to devDependencies
2. Change env-var of heroku (NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true, NODE_ENV=production)
3. heroku's `npm install` will run without devDependencies and will not result in an error

But It will be an error as before...

Is there a way to not install devDependencies when running `npm install` on heroku? Is there another way to generate ReviewApp?